# ordered dither with IM v7.0.2

Tags: imagemagick

The recent version 7 of IM gives strange results when doing order dithering. The Posterized Ordered Dither Expansion [example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/bugs/ordered-dither/): `magick convert gradient.png -ordered-dither o8x8,6 od_o8x8_6.gif` yields just 2bpp bitmap.

Input:[image]

Preffered output:[image]

Actual output:[image]

Is this an error or there is some syntax change?

Comment: I can confirm that the behaviour you see occurs the same on OSX between v6.? and v7.?. I haven't seen anything that would indicate this is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the OrderedPosterizeImage feature hasn't yet been ported from IM6 to IM7.  IM7 falls back on the original bi-level OrderedDitherImage method, ignoring the ",6" part of the specification.
I've posted a [feature request](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30337&p=136898#p136898) on the ImageMagick discourse server.

Comment: Top sleuthing, Glenn. Thank you.